# How to solve Gradle Compatibility Issue on appcompat-v7:28.0.0 whenever parse:1.20.0 is implemented?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I'm implementing Parse SDK 1.20.0 on my kotlin android application, but whenever I implemented it and sync the gradle, I got a gradle incompatibility issue on appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

This is for kotlin application that connected with Parse SDK made by using Android Studio 3.4. in the past, I've tried to change the appcompat to smaller version and seem to end up having a gradle incompatibility.

the code on build.gradle (Module:app) :

[Image For The Real Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14kZD.png)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Parse SDK implementation
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.20.0"
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:ktx:1.20.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

i expected the gradle will have a compatibility, but the result always show the incompatibility.